# Problem with creation of uiimageView in arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uiimageview

here is my code :

```
-(void) createImage {


UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];

 [imageViewArray addObject:imageView];

[[self view] addSubview:imageView];

[imageView release];


}

-(void)moveImage{
for(int i=0; i< [imageViewArray count];i++){
    UIImageView *imageView = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
}
```

I try to use an array in this code but, it doesn't work, indeed I have never used array, and it would be cool if someone could tell me where is my error ;thank you . sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: there is no error, but there is no image of "imageView" on the screen

Comment: How is `randomPointSquare` implemented? Probably it is putting the image views off screen.

Comment: no the problem is not from randomPointSquare because it works without my implementation of array, the problem must come from the array

Comment: @bernard where do you initialize the array?

Comment: in my ".h". NSMutableArray*imageViewArray

Comment: That's not enough. In viewDidLoad, you need to initialize the array, as sternr has shown below.

Comment: ok, now imageView appears on my screen but something strange happen, imageView appears then i moves during two seconds(because createImage is called every two seconds) then another imageView is created and the previous one stop moving in his previous direction and goes in the same direction of the new. it's maybe hard to understand but it is what happen

Answer (score 1):

You'r missing:
imageViewArray = `[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`